# How to float TWO Anchor links, align text horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css

Here's the image of what I'm trying to achieve for better explanation

[image]

What I'm dealing with is:

- There are 2 anchor links floating with each other.
- The two anchors content or number of words inside of it varies. The
  anchor is the next and previous post of my wordpress blog. Please
  refer to
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link and
  and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link for
  reference.
- Both have equal size (height and width). The height automatically adjust depending on the content of the other anchor.
- There's a border line in the middle.
- Text should be vertically and horizontally aligned.

[You can see the live example of what I'm trying to copy for better explanation](http://www.theverge.com/2014/9/19/6540133/best-halloween-books-spooky-stories).

[Here's my code and fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bendaggers/wn2aznxt/8/)

```
<div class="holdmetight">
    <div class="prev"><a href="/">TITLE OF PREVIOUS POST HERE</a></div>
    <div class="next"><a href="/">TITLE OF NEXT POST HERE</a></div>
</div>

.holdmetight {width:100%; max-width:1023px; position:relative; display:block; }
.next, .prev { min-height:35px; height:100%; text-align:center; height:100px;}
.prev { display:block; background:#CCC; width: 100% auto; }
.next {float:left; border-right:1px solid #eceff0; background: #AAA;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic layout with `display: table`.

Benefits of `display: table`:

- Easily vertically center the text with `vertical-align: middle`
- Both divs maintain the same height based on the others content

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/bolise/1/edit)

HTML / CSS

```css
.holdmetight {
    display: table;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-top: solid 2px #000;
}

/* the > selector targets direct div children of .holdmetight */
.holdmetight > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}
.prev {
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="holdmetight">
    <div class="prev">
        <a href="/">
          TITLE OF PREVIOUS POST HERE.
          This is a particulary long title 
          that will push both divs down.
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <a href="/">
          TITLE OF NEXT POST HERE
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is perfect! I've tried adding a very long content and it works perfect! http://jsfiddle.net/bendaggers/wn2aznxt/16/

Comment: @KareenLagasca - good to hear :) `display: table` does not always get the recognition it deserves. It can be very useful!

Comment: And of course (CSS) Tables have their own disadvantages. Use them with care.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wn2aznxt/7/)

```
    .holdmetight {width:100%; max-width:1023px; position:relative; display:block; }
.next, .prev { min-height:35px; height:100%; text-align:center; height:100px; display:inline-block;}
.prev { background:#CCC; width: 100% auto; }
.next { border-right:1px solid #eceff0; background: #AAA;}
```

add padding according to need

Comment: I edited my fiddle. can you take a look again. and the text inside of the anchor should be in the middle (horizontally and vertically aligned).